# Подскажите пожалуйста простыми словами, что такое Итератор?

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать js. И слышу это слово уже к который раз.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Answer (score 0):

Он нужен для выборки данных из массива. Просто и понятно.

Comment: А ключей объектов? А символов строки?  А мапов и сетов? Тогда уж "он нужен для совершения итераций" ничем не хуже. И "перебор" лучше "выборки" смотрится в определении операции перебора